# Having problems solving and graphing this problem

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Graph the curve  = sin() + sin(1.5) ,  = cos(). Then find the length of the curve
correct to four decimal places. Be sure to graph the entire shape.

I tired ParametricPlot[{Sin (t) + Sin (1.5 t), Cos (t)}, {t, -4, 4}] but nothing came out to the graph

I also tried solve[(-sin (t))/(Cos (t) + Cos (1.5 t)*1.5)]
but it didnt come out right

Comment: Functions use square brackets [ ] not parentheses ( ), and all commands are case sensitive, so sin is not the same as Sin.

Comment: What is section 10.2 [DASH] #47?  Did you just copy-paste a homework problem here?  Those are emphatically not welcome.  [This online book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) is a great resource for beginners.

Comment: Sorry, i wont do it again, but i have another question when i put in
Solve[-sin[t]/(Cos[t] + Cos[1.5 t]*1.5)] im supposed to be getting a decimal but im not getting anything, what am i doing wrong

Comment: capitalize 's' in `Sin`, and `Solve` takes an equation.  Read [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), and follow the examples.

Comment: @mylesroddy there is nothing to solve for in your `Solve` function. Mathematically, it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

For the "entire shape" you must extend the range of `t` to a range of `24 Pi/5`

```
x[t_] := Sin[t] + Sin[3/2 t];
y[t_] := Cos[t];

pp = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -12 Pi/5, 12 Pi/5}]
```

[image]

```
length = NIntegrate[Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2],
   {t, -12Pi/5, 12Pi/5}]//NumberForm[#, {6, 4}]&

(*  18.4730  *)
```

Breaking the integral into multiple segments

```
intervals = Partition[
   SortBy[t /. Solve[{x[t] == 0, -12 Pi/5 <= t <= 12 Pi/5}, t], N],
   2, 1];

Total[NIntegrate[Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2],
    {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ intervals]

(*  18.473  *)
```

Comment: would i just press enter after implementing that or should i put in an extra step

Comment: When i Implement it i get something different from 18.4730

Comment: Did you clear previous definitions or else start with a fresh kernel?

Comment: should i clear Nintegrate?